# POST to Different Action name from the GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a controller which displays user profiles the Action for showing a profile is just under Index : its /User/123 to show user 123. This is set on route map like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "User",
            url: "User/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```

Now my controller looks something like this:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        *edited out for simplicity*
        return View(model);
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Follow(int id)
    {
        *edited out for simplicity*
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new { id });
    }
}
```

And my web form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Follow", "User", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Follow!" class="btn btn-success" />
            }
```

Now the GET works perfectly but when I submit the POST it isn't handing over the user id from the url /user/123.

Do I need to perform an extra action in the `Html.BeginForm` if I am going from a GET on Index to a POST on Follow in order for it to hand over the {id} ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `BeginForm` overload that takes `RouteValues` and pass the id from the Url using the `RequestContext`

```
Html.BeginForm("Follow","User", new { id = @Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] }, FormMethod.Post);
```